# why i get error while importing project in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

I am having problem while importing project in eclips.
Actually there is no problem in importing project in from the same computer but if i am taking the project from another computer and importing it in my system's eclipse , it does show many errors.
Can any body tell me how to deal with this situation ?

Answer (score 0):

It probably has something to do with some file paths on your computer not being the same as on the one that you copy from. But without any more details about the errors you get it is really hard to say.

You can open the .project file in a text editor and see if there is anything suspicious in it.

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention if your project has some linked resources like other related projects. As you can see in the .project file, the path to that resources is absolute.
Moreover, did you used the correct import procedure to import the project in the workspace?